# call back member function in c++

Tags: c++, c, linux

```
    class scanner
    {
        private:
            string mRootFilePath;
            static int  AddToIndex( const char *,const struct stat *,int);  
        public:

            scanner(string aRootFilePath){
            mRootFilePath = aRootFilePath;
            }       

            string GetFilepath(){
                return mRootFilePath;
            }
            void Start();
    };


    int  scanner :: AddToIndex(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb,int typeflag)
    {

        fprintf(stderr,"\n%s\t%d",fpath,typeflag);
        return 0;
    }

    void scanner :: Start()
    {
        ftw(mRootFilePath.c_str,(int (*)( const char *,const struct stat *,int))scanner :: AddToIndex,200);
    }


main()
{

int i;
scanner test(".");
test.Start();


}
```

When I compile this code I get error message

```
 main.c: In member function ‘void scanner::Start()’:
main.c:34: error: argument of type ‘const char* (std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::)()const’ does not match ‘const char*’
```

ftw function calls the call back function in this case AddToIndex() function which is a member function of the class "scanner".. how can make this member function AddToIndex as a call back function? And How to resolve this issue...

Comment: @LiraLuna: http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftw It's a well-known standard library function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your call to `ftw`, the first parameter is `mRootFilePath.c_str`.  Perhaps you want `mRootFilePath.c_str()` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from Managu's answer, don't forget to make sure that your `static` member function uses C linkage (`extern "C"`) - depending on the implementation, you may not be able to pass a pointer to a function with the default C++ linkage where a pointer to C function is expected (when ABIs differ).