# C++ call back function

Tags: c++, linux, visual-c++

I get the following error when passing the C++ callback function for the CRYPTO_set_locking_callback.

```
Error C2664: 'CRYPTO_set_locking_callback' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
'void (__cdecl *)(int,int,char *,int)' to
'void (__cdecl *)(int,int,const char *,int)'
This conversion requires a reinterpret_cast, a C-style cast or
function-style cast
```

My code looks like this:

```
CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(&MyFunc::lock_callback);

void MyFunc::lock_callback(int mode, int type, char *file, int line)
{

    (void)file;
    (void)line;
    if (mode & CRYPTO_LOCK)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(lockarray[type]));
    }
    else
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(lockarray[type]));
    }
}
```

I tried reinterpret cast with no luck and not sure what is the correct way of doing it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message, your function's third argument is supposed to be a `const char*`:

```
void MyFunc::lock_callback(int mode, int type, const char* file, int line)
```

This shouldn't be a problem, seeing as you're not even using it.

---

You can see this in [the documentation](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/threads.html), too:

```
void CRYPTO_lock(int mode, int n, const char *file, int line);
```

Comment: I am trying to use the example from "http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threaded-ssl.html".The warning disappeared with the following change "CRYPTO_set_locking_callback((void (*)( int,int,const char*,int))MyFunc:: lock_callback);. Is this fix is acceptable?. Refereed from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506313/call-back-member-function-in-c

Comment: @user1427180: Probably, but why are you trying to apply horrid hacks? That code works because it's C, and uses a feature of C that cares very little about the types of parameters (`CRYPTO_set_locking_callback((void (*)())lock_callback)`). C++, however, cares greatly. Just fix your function signature to be correct.

Comment: I did correct the signature and changed the CRYPTO_set_locking_callback(&MyFunc:: lock_callback). I was curious if the other hack was acceptable?. Thanks for your reply and will accept your answer.

Comment: @user1427180: I think it rather depends on your definition of "acceptable". :) In some cultures, it is deemed "acceptable" to mate with eight year olds. Not in mine.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
void MyFunc::lock_callback(int mode, int type, const char *file, int line){}
```